# Implicit conversion from type Char[] to string is not possible

Tags: c#, string, char, type-conversion

I want to do the following but I get this

> Error: an Implicit conversion from type Char[] to string is not
>   possible.

```
string Pattern2 = (Convert.ToDateTime(currMail.CreationTime).ToString(" dd-MMM-yyyy HH-mm")).ToArray();
```

Does anybody have any idea as on how to deal with this?

Comment: Remove the `.ToArray()` call. What is it supposed to be doing? And really, you are calling a method `.ToString()` and you want to assign to a `string`. I cannot begin to imagine how that extra `.ToArray()` would look "OK" to anyone.

Comment: eh, maybe to a beginner :)
what do you mean with "ToString() and you want to assign to a string"
should I make it a String with a big S?

Comment: @gbbb: `string` and `System.String` are aliases; there's no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `.ToArray()`:

```
string Pattern2 = Convert.ToDateTime(currMail.CreationTime).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH-mm");
```

Comment: do you have any Idea why @Soner Gonul told me i was doing something wrong because i was assigning ToString() to a string?

Comment: @gbb - he was advising you to take out `.ToArray` as I did.  In a nutshell, you are converting `CreationTime` to a `DateTime` object and then parsing it as a `string` - which is fine because `Pattern2` is of type `string`, there was no need to call `.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers point out, your call to `ToArray` is not just unnecessary, it is in this case actively harmful. You already have a string in hand, you need a string, so don't convert the string to an array of char; just use the string.

However, for your future reference it *is* possible to convert an array of char to a string, just not via an implicit or explicit conversion. The syntax for that is:

```
char[] characters = whatever;
string str = new String(characters);
```

Finally, the documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s1wwdcbf.aspx

Beginners should familiarize themselves with this documentation; there's a lot of good stuff in there.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't need to use `.ToArray()` method at all. You already using `.ToString()` method for assigning to your `Pattern2` variable.

Just use as;

```
string Pattern2 = Convert.ToDateTime(currMail.CreationTime).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH-mm");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 string Pattern2 = Convert.ToDateTime(currMail.CreationTime).ToString(" dd-MMM-yyyy HH-mm");
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign a char[] to a string, which requires conversion from the char[] to a string. As the error says, this is not done implicitly, i.e. behind the scenes. This is done to prevent silly mistakes.

You are expected to make an explicit conversion (create a string from the array and then assign it).

In your case you have a string and convert it to an array before assigning it to Pattern2. Just don't convert the string to an array.

```
string Pattern2 = (Convert.ToDateTime(currMail.CreationTime).ToString(" dd-MMM-yyyy HH-mm"));
```